# LWJGL Mouse carrying out command multiple times randomly

Tags: lwjgl

Im trying to set my LWJGL Mouse to grabbed and not grabbed when i push the left mouse button. 
However this has proven to become a tricky matter since the LWJGL mouse for some matter executes the command multiple times randomly. For an example:

```
if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            Mouse.setGrabbed( !Mouse.isGrabbed() );
            System.out.println("Pushed");
        } 
       if(Mouse.isGrabbed()){
           camera.processMouse(1, 80, -80);
```

If i run this code it will print "Pushed" several times randomly per push. As you can imagine that becomes a problem when i try to set my Mouse to grabbed true or false from each click. the times i have tried this code it has printed "Pushed" 4 - 7 times per click

is there any way to make the Mouse only carry out the command once per click?

many thanks in advance to everyone who will take time to help me solve this problem.

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to check a boolean field which you flip on the first iteration of the block after the mouse is clicked or released to tell you if this is the first time since the click that the if block has been executed. Here's an example:

```
private boolean alreadyClicked;
void someMethod(){
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
        if(!alreadyClicked){
            alreadyClicked = true;
            // do what you want to do when the mouse is clicked
        }
    }
    else{
        alreadyClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the event buffer of the Mouse class to detect clicks like this:

```
while(Mouse.next()) {
    if(Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) {
        if(Mouse.getEventButtonState()) {
            // clicked
        }
        else{
            // released
        }
    }
}
```